# How to order rows within groups in the big dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a relatively big dataframe (1.5 Gb), and I want to group rows by `ID` and order rows by column `VAL` in ascending order within each group.

```
df =

ID   VAL  COL
1A   2    BB
1A   1    AA
2B   2    CC
3C   3    SS
3C   1    YY
3C   2    XX
```

This is the expected result:

```
df =

ID   VAL  COL
1A   1    AA
1A   2    BB
2B   2    CC
3C   1    YY
3C   2    XX
3C   3    SS
```

This is what I tried, but it runs very long time. Is there any faster solution?:

```
df = df.groupby("ID").apply(pd.DataFrame.sort, 'VAL')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a big `df` and speed is important, try a little `numpy`

```
# note order of VAL first, then ID is intentional
# np.lexsort sorts by right most column first
df.iloc[np.lexsort((df.VAL.values, df.ID.values))]

   ID  VAL COL
1  1A    1  AA
0  1A    2  BB
2  2B    2  CC
4  3C    1  YY
5  3C    2  XX
3  3C    3  SS
```

---

***super charged***

```
v = df.values
i, j = np.searchsorted(df.columns.values, ['VAL', 'ID'])
s = np.lexsort((v[:, i], v[:, j]))
pd.DataFrame(v[s], df.index[s], df.columns)
```

***timing***

[image]

Comment: These timings are on what `df.shape`? I don't think `df.iloc[...]` method would be faster than `sort_values` for large df.

Comment: @JohnGalt sample given. Super charged version should be good. If I have a chance later, I'll update with larger sample.

Answer (score 2):

`sort_values` on `'ID', 'VAL'` should give you

```
In [39]: df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'VAL'])
Out[39]:
   ID  VAL COL
1  1A    1  AA
0  1A    2  BB
2  2B    2  CC
4  3C    1  YY
5  3C    2  XX
3  3C    3  SS
```

Time it for your use-case

```
In [89]: dff.shape
Out[89]: (12000, 3)

In [90]: %timeit dff.sort_values(by=['ID', 'VAL'])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.62 ms per loop

In [91]: %timeit dff.iloc[np.lexsort((dff.VAL.values, dff.ID.values))]
100 loops, best of 3: 8.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: Note that there is an `inplace` parameter to avoid having to perform an extra assignment.